# Zend Framework 2 Doctrine integration (November 2012)

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

What is the best way to integrate ZF2 and Doctrine as of now (November 2012)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same that it has been couple of months ago [using DoctrineORMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I've just finished to integrate it following [this blog](http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/).